# Updating PowerShell scripts

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-5.0

How can I update the PowerShell scripts according to the latest commands of PowerShell 5.0 or PowerShell 4.0?
For example I updated

```
$s = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
```

with

```
$s = $PSScriptRoot
```

so this makes my script little less complex and easy to understand.

Because currently the scripts which I have are old and created using commands supported in 2.0 so I want to update them with latest cmdlets.

Comment: Umm... you open the scripts in your preferred editor and modify them?

Comment: But i don't know with which commands i should replace the older commands to make the script little small and less complex to understand or else i simply have to search for new alternate commands for the old one's.

Comment: There is no magical "upgrade my legacy PowerShell code to a newer version" command.

Comment: Okay,will have to update each script manually by searching on net then.

Comment: make copies first...

Comment: Sure..It will be the first step that i will do before updating script.